# Arquivos não usados no site são carregados?

Tags: html, ftp

Digamos que eu tenha no ftp de um site vários arquivos, como imagens que não estou usando na construção do mesmo, imagens obsoletas ou arquivos que quero guardar nesse domínio. 
Quando acesso esse site, esses arquivos, principalmente imagens, são carregados enquanto o meu site é carregado?

Comment: Não são carregadas nem interferem em nada no site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não são carregadas nem interferem em nada no site.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Essas imagens só serão carregadas se você fizer referencia no seu site!! 
Do contrário pode ficar despreocupado que não interfere!!!

Comment: Achei a resposta boa ao contrário do comentário acima, muito obrigado, amigo!

Comment: Sempre que precisar estamos aqui! =)